# How to add buffering while using getc and putc

Tags: c, file, cl

I want to make copy/paste with using c FILE but i need to add read/write buffer too and I am not sure how to add it. Is there any function similar to regular read/write..Code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* fsource, * fdestination;

    printf("enter the name of source file:\n");
    char sourceName[20], destinationName[20];
    strcpy(sourceName, argv[1]);
    strcpy(destinationName, argv[2]);


    fsource = fopen(sourceName, "r");
    if (fsource == NULL)
        printf("read file did not open\n");
    else
        printf("read file opened sucessfully!\n");
    fdestination = fopen(destinationName, "w");
    if (fdestination == NULL)
        printf("write file did not open\n");
    else
        printf("write file opened sucessfully!\n");

    char pen = fgets(fsource);
    while (pen != EOF)
    {
        fputc(pen, fdestination);
        pen = fgets(fsource);
    }


    fclose(fsource);
    fclose(fdestination);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: i changed fgets to fgetc j

Comment: Proper error message are written to stderr and contain the reason for the failure: `if( fsource == NULL ) { perror(sourceName); exit(EXIT_FAILURE; }`

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all to me.  `fgets` and `fgetc` are buffered reads.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Don't copy argv.  If you want a more readable name than `argv[1]` (a perfectly reasonable thing), there's no need to copy the data.  Instead, just do `const char *sourceName = argv[1];`  By make sourceName an array of size 20 and then using an unchecked `strcpy`, you expose an easy buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reworking of your code (sans some error handling) that reads and writes in 256-byte increments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *sourceName = argv[0];
  char destName[256];
  snprintf(destName, 256, "%s.copy", sourceName);
  printf("Copying %s -> %s\n", sourceName, destName);
  FILE *fsource = fopen(sourceName, "rb");
  FILE *fdest = fopen(destName, "w");
  char buffer[256];
  for (;;) {
    size_t bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, 256, fsource);
    if (bytesRead == 0) {
      break;
    }
    if (fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, fdest) != bytesRead) {
      printf("Failed to write all bytes!");
      break;
    }
    printf("Wrote %ld bytes, position now %ld\n", bytesRead, ftell(fdest));
  }
  fclose(fsource);
  fclose(fdest);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is e.g.

```
$ ./so64481514
Copying ./so64481514 -> ./so64481514.copy
Wrote 256 bytes, position now 256
Wrote 256 bytes, position now 512
Wrote 256 bytes, position now 768
Wrote 256 bytes, position now 1024
[...]
Wrote 168 bytes, position now 12968
```

Comment: Why are you perpetuating the travesty of copying argv?

Comment: @WilliamPursell To make this self-contained without prompting the user for filenames.

Comment: But instead of using `strncpy` it seems cleaner to demonstrate `char *destName = argv[i]`

Comment: That'd need bounds checking re argc and usage instructions for the program. My point here was that you can run the program and it makes a copy of itself.